# How to set a VF variable to be the same value as another VF variable without executing apex?

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way to set the value of a Vf object variable to be the same value as another VF variable? So the user enters a value into a screen field, can i take that value and assign it to another VF variable before the user has to press any buttons etc?, ie before Apex is executed?. Here is an example

```
<apex:selectList value="{!offer.Type_of_Contract__c}" multiselect="false" >

    <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeOfContract}"/>

    <apex:inputHidden value="{!offer.Type_of_Contract2__c}"/>  

</apex:selectList>
```

Can the value chosen by the user for `type_of_Contract__c` be passed to Type `_Of_Contract2` in the VF code without executing apex or the user having to press buttons etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use jQuery. Code will be more complicated without that.

First In your page, give selectList and your inputHidden an Id:

```
<apex:selectList id="typeOfContactSelect" value="{!offer.Type_of_Contract__c}" multiselect="false" >

    <apex:selectOptions value="{!TypeOfContract}"/>

    <apex:inputHidden id="typeOfContactInput" value="{!offer.Type_of_Contract2__c}"/>  

</apex:selectList>
```

Then in jQuery:

```
$("select[id$='typeOfContactSelect']").change(function(){
    var typeOfContact = $("select[id$='typeOfContactSelect']").val();
    $("input[id$='typeOfContactInput']").val(typeOfContact);
});
```

Comment: Hi Lance, we are not using JQuery. It is something I may look into. How much more complicated does the code get without it.?  
Can it be done via JScript?

Comment: @GeorgePiumatti You need to use the Salesforce way to get the Id of each DOM element. And do the vanilla JS way of value assignment and retrieval, which will be some extra work unless you are really familiar with that. For me, I wouldn't recommend using vanilla Javascript. Either use JQuery or some big framework, e.g. AngularJS. Plus, there is no steep learning curve for jQuery as well. After 10 minutes, you will be fine

Comment: Hi Lance, presumably the JQuery code gets called immediately after the VF code above?

Comment: @GeorgePiumatti jQuery code is javascript code. It is just a library. We usually use $(document).ready() to wrap the code which should be executed after DOM elements are loaded. You can google that up. But yes, if you don't wrap it, all the jQuery code is just javascript code so it will be executed